# Support vector machine not running as expected

Tags: java, machine-learning, svm

I'm implementing the SVM as described here:

http://karpathy.github.io/neuralnets/

Here is their description: (it uses just the function: f(x)= ax + by +c)

Support Vector Machine "Force Specification":

"If we feed a positive datapoint through the SVM circuit and the output value is 
less than 1, pull on the circuit with force +1. This is a positive example so we 
want the score to be higher for it.

Conversely, if we feed a negative datapoint through the SVM and the output is 
greater than -1, then the circuit is giving this datapoint dangerously high score: Pull on the circuit downwards with force -1.

In addition to the pulls above, always add a small amount of pull on the parameters a,b (notice, not on c!) that pulls them towards zero. You can think of both a,b as being attached to a physical spring that is attached at zero. Just as with a physical spring, this will make the pull proprotional to the value of each of a,b

For example, if a becomes very high it will experience a strong pull of magnitude |a| back towards zero. This pull is something we call regularization, and it ensures that neither of our parameters a or b gets disproportionally large.

This would be undesirable because both a,b get multiplied to the input features x,y (remember the equation is a*x + b*y + c), so if either of them is too high, our classifier would be overly sensitive to these features.

This isn't a nice property because features can often be noisy in practice, so we want our classifier to change relatively smoothly if they wiggle around."

Their data consists of 6 (x,y) points, each with their respective label:

```
var data = []; var labels = [];
data.push([1.2, 0.7]); labels.push(1);
data.push([-0.3, -0.5]); labels.push(-1);
data.push([3.0, 0.1]); labels.push(1);
data.push([-0.1, -1.0]); labels.push(-1);
data.push([-1.0, 1.1]); labels.push(-1);
data.push([2.1, -3]); labels.push(1);
```

This is their code (in Javascript maybe?) for the "circuits" (used in backpropagation). It consists of some Add-Gate and some Multiply-Gate with their respective backpropagation property (don't really know what to say here) but I guess this much would suffice. If not, you can follow the link , it's in Chapter 1, BackPropagation:

```
// A circuit: it takes 5 Units (x,y,a,b,c) and outputs a single Unit
// It can also compute the gradient w.r.t. its inputs
var Circuit = function() {
  // create some gates
  this.mulg0 = new multiplyGate();
  this.mulg1 = new multiplyGate();
  this.addg0 = new addGate();
  this.addg1 = new addGate();
};
Circuit.prototype = {
  forward: function(x,y,a,b,c) {
    this.ax = this.mulg0.forward(a, x); // a*x
    this.by = this.mulg1.forward(b, y); // b*y
    this.axpby = this.addg0.forward(this.ax, this.by); // a*x + b*y
    this.axpbypc = this.addg1.forward(this.axpby, c); // a*x + b*y + c
    return this.axpbypc;
  },
  backward: function(gradient_top) { // takes pull from above
    this.axpbypc.grad = gradient_top;
    this.addg1.backward(); // sets gradient in axpby and c
    this.addg0.backward(); // sets gradient in ax and by
    this.mulg1.backward(); // sets gradient in b and y
    this.mulg0.backward(); // sets gradient in a and x
  }
}
```

It is supposed to output the following:

```
training accuracy at iteration 0: 0.3333333333333333
training accuracy at iteration 25: 0.3333333333333333
training accuracy at iteration 50: 0.5
training accuracy at iteration 75: 0.5
training accuracy at iteration 100: 0.3333333333333333
training accuracy at iteration 125: 0.5
training accuracy at iteration 150: 0.5
training accuracy at iteration 175: 0.5
training accuracy at iteration 200: 0.5
training accuracy at iteration 225: 0.6666666666666666
training accuracy at iteration 250: 0.6666666666666666
training accuracy at iteration 275: 0.8333333333333334
training accuracy at iteration 300: 1
training accuracy at iteration 325: 1
training accuracy at iteration 350: 1
training accuracy at iteration 375: 1
```

I just follow their instruction, but for the "Regularization" I don't think I really grasped it. It says: Give a and b a force toward 0 and proportional to their value. Here is what I understand: If you give it a force, you change ít's gradient over time, that means you add the current gradient with a value proportional to it's value. Its in the function "newGrad" in class SVM, used by the function "regularization()".

I think this is probably the place things I went wrong. However I also suspect about the lack of a "Stochastic Gradient Descent".

The description on the website:

```
f(x,y)=ax+by+c
In this expression we think of x and y as the inputs (the 2D vectors) and a,b,c as the parameters of the function that we will want to learn. For example, if a = 1, b = -2, c = -1, then the function will take the first datapoint ([1.2, 0.7]) and output 1 * 1.2 + (-2) * 0.7 + (-1) = -1.2. Here is how the training will work:

We select a random datapoint and feed it through the circuit
We will interpret the output of the circuit as a confidence that the datapoint has class +1. (i.e. very high values = circuit is very certain datapoint has class +1 and very low values = circuit is certain this datapoint has class -1.)
We will measure how well the prediction aligns with the provided labels. Intuitively, for example, if a positive example scores very low, we will want to tug in the positive direction on the circuit, demanding that it should output higher value for this datapoint. Note that this is the case for the the first datapoint: it is labeled as +1 but our predictor unction only assigns it value -1.2. We will therefore tug on the circuit in positive direction; We want the value to be higher.
The circuit will take the tug and backpropagate it to compute tugs on the inputs a,b,c,x,y
Since we think of x,y as (fixed) datapoints, we will ignore the pull on x,y. If you're a fan of my physical analogies, think of these inputs as pegs, fixed in the ground.
On the other hand, we will take the parameters a,b,c and make them respond to their tug (i.e. we'll perform what we call a parameter update). This, of course, will make it so that the circuit will output a slightly higher score on this particular datapoint in the future.
Iterate! Go back to step 1.
The training scheme I described above, is commonly referred as Stochastic Gradient Descent.
```

I think this is identical to the Perceptron algorithm.

However rigth after this part they switched right to SVM and I thought they were supposed to use it as part of the SVM, but they just said: "Now lets train the SVM with Stochastic Gradient Descent" but when I read it I couldn't find anything :

```
var data = []; var labels = [];
data.push([1.2, 0.7]); labels.push(1);
data.push([-0.3, -0.5]); labels.push(-1);
data.push([3.0, 0.1]); labels.push(1);
data.push([-0.1, -1.0]); labels.push(-1);
data.push([-1.0, 1.1]); labels.push(-1);
data.push([2.1, -3]); labels.push(1);
var svm = new SVM();

// a function that computes the classification accuracy
var evalTrainingAccuracy = function() {
  var num_correct = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var x = new Unit(data[i][0], 0.0);
    var y = new Unit(data[i][1], 0.0);
    var true_label = labels[i];

    // see if the prediction matches the provided label
    var predicted_label = svm.forward(x, y).value > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    if(predicted_label === true_label) {
      num_correct++;
    }
  }
  return num_correct / data.length;
};

// the learning loop
for(var iter = 0; iter < 400; iter++) {
  // pick a random data point
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
  var x = new Unit(data[i][0], 0.0);
  var y = new Unit(data[i][1], 0.0);
  var label = labels[i];
  svm.learnFrom(x, y, label);

  if(iter % 25 == 0) { // every 10 iterations... 
    console.log('training accuracy at iter ' + iter + ': ' + evalTrainingAccuracy());
  }
}
```

I suspect I'm missing something very important. Please help me, thank you very much!

Here is my source code (in Java) :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication7;

/**
 *
 * @author truong
 */
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


//import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author truong
 */
public class JavaApplication7 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        SVM TestSVM ;
        float step_size=0.001f;
        float pull,score;
        //data.push([1.2, 0.7]); labels.push(1);
        //data.push([-0.3, -0.5]); labels.push(-1);
        //data.push([3.0, 0.1]); labels.push(1);
        //data.push([-0.1, -1.0]); labels.push(-1);
        //data.push([-1.0, 1.1]); labels.push(-1);
        //data.push([2.1, -3]); labels.push(1);
        float[] datax  = {1.2f, -0.3f, 3.0f, -0.1f, -1.0f, 2.1f} ;
        float[] datay  = {0.7f, -0.5f, 0.1f, -1.0f,  1.1f,  -3f} ;
        boolean[] labels={true,false,true,false,false,true};
        float accuracy,result;
        int i,length = 6,randint;
        int iter,correct;
        Random rand= new Random();
        boolean type,label;
        TestSVM = new SVM();
        TestSVM.init(1.0f, -2.0f, -1.0f);
        float a =1, b =-2, c=-1;
        float x,y;
        for (iter=0; iter<= 400; iter++){
            randint = rand.nextInt(length);
            TestSVM.setSVM(datax[randint], datay[randint], labels[randint]);




            if (iter %25 ==0){            
                correct =0;
                for (i=0 ; i<length; i++){
                    result = TestSVM.calculate(datax[i],datay[i]);
                    //result = a * datax[i] + b * datay[i] + c;
                    type= (result>0);
                    //if (result >=0)
                    //    type = true;
                    //else
                    //    type = false;
                    if (type == labels[i])
                        correct++;
                }
                accuracy = ((float) correct ) / length;
                System.out.println("Training accuracy at the "+ iter +" iteration:"+ accuracy);
            }

        }

    }

}

class AddGate{
    private float gradx, grady;
    private float backx, backy;
    final float step = 0.0001f;
    public float calculate(float x, float y){
        return (x+y);
    }
    public void setGradx(float x, float y){
        float dif;
        dif = this.calculate(x+step,y) - this.calculate(x, y);
        gradx = (dif / step );
    }

    public void setGrady(float x, float y){
        float dif;
        dif = this.calculate(x,y +step) - this.calculate(x,y);
        grady = (dif / step);
    }   

    public float setAddGate(float x, float y){
        float val;
        val = calculate(x,y);
        setGradx(x,y);
        setGrady(x,y);
        return val;
    }

    public void backWard(float out){
        backx += gradx * out;
        backy += grady * out;
    }

    public float getBackx(){
        return backx;
    }

    public float getBacky(){
        return backy;
    }
}

class MulGate{
    private float gradq, gradz;
    private float backq, backz;
    private final float step = 0.0001f;
    public float calculate(float q, float z){
        return (q*z);
    }
    public void setGradq(float q, float z){
        float dif;
        dif = this.calculate(q+step,z) - this.calculate(q, z);
        gradq = (dif / step );
    }

    public void setGradz(float q, float z){
        float dif;
        dif = this.calculate(q,z +step) - this.calculate(q,z);
        gradz = (dif / step);
    }

    public float setMulGate(float q, float z){
        float val;
        val =calculate(q,z);
        setGradq(q,z);
        setGradz(q,z);
        return val;
    }

    public void backWard(float out){
        backq += gradq * out;
        backz += gradz * out;
    }    

    public float getBackq(){
        return backq;
    }

    public float getBackz(){
        return backz;
    }
}

class SigmoidGate{
    private float backx, backy, backz;
    private AddGate AGate = new AddGate();
    private MulGate MGate = new MulGate();

    public void SigmoidGate(){
        AGate = new AddGate();
        MGate = new MulGate();
    }

    public float calculate (float x, float y, float z){
        float q;
        q = AGate.calculate(x,y);
        return MGate.calculate(q,z);
    }

    public void setBackProp(float x, float y, float z){
        float q;
        float tmp;
        q=AGate.setAddGate(x,y);
        MGate.setMulGate(q,z);
        MGate.backWard(1);
        AGate.backWard(MGate.getBackq());
        backx = AGate.getBackx();
        backy = AGate.getBacky();
        backz = MGate.getBackz();
    }

    public float getBackx(){
        return backx;
    }

    public float getBacky(){
        return backy;
    }

    public float getBackz(){
        return backz;
    }

}

class GoodGate{
    private float backa,backb,backc;
    private float grada,gradb,gradc;
    private MulGate ax,by;
    private AddGate axPby,axPbyPc;          //ax + by and ax+by+c

    public void GoodGate(){
        ax = new MulGate();
        by = new MulGate();
        axPby = new AddGate();
        axPbyPc = new AddGate();
    }

    public float calculate(float a, float x, float b, float y, float c){
        return (a*x + b*y + c  );
    }

    public float setBackProp(float a, float x, float b, float y, float c, float pull){
        float val,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3;

        ax = new MulGate();
        by = new MulGate();
        axPby = new AddGate();
        axPbyPc = new AddGate();
        val = calculate(a,x,b,y,c);
        //forward pass
        tmp1 = ax.setMulGate(a, x);
        tmp2 = by.setMulGate(b, y);
        tmp3 = axPby.setAddGate(tmp1,tmp2);
        axPbyPc.setAddGate(tmp3, c);
        //backward pass
        axPbyPc.backWard(pull);
        backc = axPbyPc.getBacky();
        axPby.backWard( axPbyPc.getBackx() );
        ax.backWard(axPby.getBackx() );
        by.backWard(axPby.getBacky() );
        backa = ax.getBackq();
        backb = by.getBackq();              

        return val;
    }

    public float getBacka(){
        return backa;
    }

    public float getBackb(){
        return backb;
    }

    public float getBackc(){
        return backc;
    }
}

class SVM{
    private GoodGate GGate;
    private float grada,gradb,gradc;
    private float a,b,c;

    public void SVM(){
        GGate = new GoodGate();
    }
    private float newGrad(float current,float curGrad){     //not very good
        float sign;
        if (current<0)
            sign = 1;
        else
            sign = -1;
        return (curGrad+  sign* Math.abs(current)) ; 
    }


    public float calculate(float x, float y){
        return GGate.calculate(a, x, b, y, c);
    }

    public void init(float firsta, float firstb, float firstc){
        a=firsta; b= firstb; c= firstc;
        grada = 0; gradb = 0; gradc = 0;
    }

    private void regularization(){
        grada = newGrad(a,grada);
        gradb = newGrad(b,gradb);
    }

    private void gradPull(float x, float y, float pull){
        GGate.setBackProp(a,x,b,y,c,pull);
        grada += GGate.getBacka();
        gradb += GGate.getBackb();
        gradc += GGate.getBackc();
    }

    public void setSVM( float x,  float y, boolean label){
        float step_size = 0.01f;
        float val;
        float pull;
        GGate = new GoodGate();
        val = GGate.calculate(a,x,b,y,c);
        //grada=0;gradb=0; gradc=0;
        if (label == true){
            if (val < 1){
                pull = 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                pull = 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            if (val> -1){
                pull = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                pull = 0;
            }
        }
        gradPull(x,y,pull);
        //regularization();
        updateSVM();
        //a += step_size * (x * pull* GGate.getBacka() - a); // -a is from the regularization
        //b += step_size * (y * pull* GGate.getBackb() - b); // -b is from the regularization
        //c += step_size * (1 * pull* GGate.getBackc() );

    }
    private void updateSVM(){
        float step_size=0.001f;
        //System.out.println("grad a is"+ grada);
        //System.out.println("grad b is"+ gradb);
        //System.out.println("grad c is"+ gradc);
        a += grada * step_size;
        b += gradb * step_size;
        c += gradc * step_size;
        //System.out.println("a is "+ a);
        //System.out.println("b is "+ b);
        //System.out.println("c is "+ c);
        //System.out.println("-----------")
;    }

    public float getA(){
        return a;
    }

    public float getB(){
        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: That link could well be an entire textbook chapter, and your code could well be a small library. No one is going to read it all. Can you please try to describe the problem you are trying to solve, your basic solution, and what and where you think is going wrong? I spent 3 minutes on that link and I saw no mention of SVM and no mention of an exact exercise that you're attempting to solve...

Comment: @IVlad My apologies, I have just included some outline on the material, hope that is enough. But I'm sure there is a "Learning a Support Vector Machine" in the site. Perharps you could use the "search" on your browser (don't know how to put it into words" . Tnanks anyway :) –